# Custom Change Tracking implementation for Entity Framework 4.0/4.1 + WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4.1, dto

I try to create a custom change tracking mechanism for Entity Framework 4.1 in my project due to use of DTOs and WCF services.

I have 2 options when it comes to update situation

1. I can simply send object's all fields to database as update, even though, not single data field has changed.(one database call may be redundant action)
2. Get previous data from database and compare with with updated one and merge the changes and send to database. (minimum two database calls + merge operation cost)

What is the best approach to select when we think about performance and if second is the choice are there any tools,helpers to automatically merge changes for me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your favorite proxy generation framework to get this job done. I designed a undo/redo and change tracking framework for MongoDB recently. I used mixins and created a wrapped up proxy-type for each entity type at run time. so whenever you fetch a document from mongodb it returns an instance of this proxy type.